# The packages installed by pip arrange scattered

Tags: python, installation, pip, package

I use the :

```
sudo -H pip3 install openstacksdk
```

installed the openstacksdk in my mac, and I use Finder goto the directory as below:

<kbd>[image]</kbd>

you know the pip install packages puts in the `site-packages/`, I find the `openstack` folder and `openstacksdk-0.9.17.dist-info` folder are constellation, and from the create time I am sure they are all created by the command upper, as we all know if user install a package there should have a gross folder outer, and the contents in the gross folder, I mean it should be like this:

```
openstack-
         |
          -openstack
         |
          -openstacksdk-0.9.17.dist-info
```

and I also find such as the `keystoneantu1` is create at the same time.

So, why in python the pip install packages arrange scattered under the `packages/` ? 
If like java's maven or iOS's cocoapods, the every package all column in a only folder.

Or if is I went wrong with the operation?

Answer (score 0):

This is exactly how setuptools/pip arrange directories. `site-packages/openstack` is your package, it's where from Python imports. *.dist-info directories are parts of pip database it uses to list/freeze/uninstall packages. Nothing to worry about.

Comment: I install the openstacksdk, the `keystoneantu1 ` installed too. and they are constellation.